# Asp.NET web app insists on loading .NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, target-framework

I have a very simple project that suddenly wants to load .NET version 2

The `<compilation>` tag in the `web.config` includes `targetFramework="4.6.1"`

The Target framework under the project properties is also set to 4.6.1

But the IISExpress instance shows version 2

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="xxx" name="x"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating the target framework in the Solution file